# Entities relation in Microservices using Entity Framework Core and Migrations

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, migration, microservices

I have two services: MatchMakingService and UserService. 
I have a migration console application using .net core and Entity Framework Core which creates a database schema for both Services.

In UserService schema there is an entity (UserInformation) which has a one-to-one relationship to an entity (UserGameInformation) of MatchMakingService.

This code is as it was in a shared Data Base for the application.

```
public class UserInformation
{
  string id {get; set;}
  string name {get; set;}
  UserGameInformation UserGameInformation {get; set;}
}

public class UserGameInformation
{
  string id {get;set;}
  string name {get;set;}
}
```

But what if i wanted to translate this to a schema-per-service architecture? Should i use a string to refer the id to the entity on a different schema and make requests whenever is needed, or can i have a foreign key to that entity and if so, is there anyway migrations to not replicate tables on each schema created?

I also would like to know, if it is good to set a unique project to create migrations for every application services and separate schema creation by each service contexts. Or is it better to use a migration for each service.

Answer (score 3):

When two microservices share a database and have some entities in common, you should use a separate project to manage the migrations (or use a code-first from an existing database-first workflow).  Each service then scaffolds it's own subset of the entities, but neither is responsible for managing the database schema.